# How to get the Type of Class using GetType

Tags: c#, reflection

Here I am using `GetType()` to get the type of `eventData` as follows,

```
public EventDescriptor(Guid id, IEvent eventData)
{
   AggregateId = id;
   EventData = eventData;
   EventType = eventData.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
}
```

which returns:

```
 "EventType":  
 "Shared.Events.EntityCreatedEvent`1[[Shared.Model.Dto.EntityDto, Shared,  
  Version=1.0.6928.25697, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Shared,  
  Version=1.0.6928.25697, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

How can I get only the **`Shared.Model.Dto.EntityDto`** from the above?
Is there any method or propertiy available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Type.FullName` to get what you need - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.type.fullname?view=netframework-4.7.2

So in your case -

```
public EventDescriptor(Guid id, IEvent eventData)
 {
   AggregateId = id;
   EventData = eventData;
   EventType = eventData.GetType().FullName;
}
```

If you want to extract the type of the generic argument of the IEvent instance, you can do this -

```
public EventDescriptor(Guid id, IEvent eventData)
 {
   AggregateId = id;
   EventData = eventData;
   if (!eventData.GetType().IsGenericType)
   {
       EventType = eventData.GetType().FullName;
   }
   else
   {
       // notice - this assumes we can take the FIRST generic argument, we don't check for others here
       EventType = eventData.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First().FullName;
   }
}
```

Comment: how should i change the above?

Comment: Edited - take a look